# Preview theme in drupal

Tags: drupal, themes, preview

I am using drupal for the first time. I have successfully developed my first drupal website to a certain extent. I have used my own custom theme for the front-end and blue marine theme for administrator. Now my client's requirement is that when he clicks on preview button before submitting the page in admin panel, he wants to see the preview in a pop-up window with the front-end's theme. Please help me with your ideas and suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

When you set the administration theme, leave the "Use administration theme for content editing" unchecked. This should allow content creation / previewing in the "front-end" theme.

EDIT: Assuming you are using Drupal 6.x

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this module - http://drupal.org/project/pagepreview it aims to give you what the page will look like on the front-end theme.

There are some caveats though, for instance the menu will not be correct if this is a new node

Comment: There is some notice on the module page (`However, it doesn't allow you to see what the entire node will look like within the context of a fully rendered page.`), but the module may suit the needs of @Gopal

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Themeing is a complicated process in Drupal, it involves many modules and hooks, so I don't think it's an easy task for a module (maybe) to do that, or in core like Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on getting a nice solution to this too. I won't post the code yet cos it's a work in progress, but essentially I make an ajax call to retrieve a known node and then replace the node content of that page with the content of the preview box before showing the merged page in a popup window.

If it works out alright I might make a module out of it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: https://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/making-accurate-responsive-node-preview-drupal-7

Patches the *Page Preview* module with some of the *Responsive Theme Preview* modules functionality for viewing the page at different screen sizes in the preview panel.

Page preview's caveats still apply though.